# Panasonic printer refuses to print

Tags: opensuse, printing

*I recently switched from Ubuntu to Opensuse because of bloatware (including Unity).*
However, I'm not able to make my LAN printer `Panasonic KX-MB 2010` work. In Ubuntu I set the printer up using [this tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10728743&postcount=6), but in Opensuse I end up with this error even though `rastertogdi` binary is copied correctly:

```
/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertogdi failed
```

I also tried [the official driver for RedHat](http://panasonic.net/pcc/support/fax/common/table/linuxdriver.html), but I end up with one of these errors (randomly):

```
/usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster failed
```

or

```
Cannot load libgs or libgs version too old then 8.0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

libgs is the ghostscript library. you'll need to install it with:

```
sudo zypper install ghostscript
```